# Why is rotation not working for iOS 5 when it is working for iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, uiviewcontroller

I have a app that has 5.0 as deployment target and 6.1 as base sdk and it all works great on a iOS 6.x device/simulator. But on 5.x my views are not rotating. I have googled around and found some Stackoverflow post on this, but I cant quite find heads and tails in it all. I think I need to implement my own subclasses of the different view controllers I use, but which and am I right?

In my app delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I use this to create my app:

```
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2, viewController3];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I create my viewController1.. like this:

```
viewController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[SearchVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchVC_iPhone" bundle:nil]];
```

I have tried implementing `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` in my SearchVC_iPhone view controller and I have tried subclassing `UINavigationController` and implementing `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` in that subclass also but it is not working out for me and I am really just guessing here.

Please can anyone who knows this stuff help me out here, what do I need to do to get this working in iOS 5.x also?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it!! The problem is the rootViewController, I have to implement shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation on the rootViewController and then all subviews starts behaving as they should. So I made my own UITabBarController subclass that implements shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation and set that as the rootViewController.

Comment: Set your problem sovled please.

Answer (score 2):

In IOS5 you may use

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation：(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

In IOS6 you may use

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried implementing shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in my view controllers, but still my views does not rotate in iOS 5.x

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on an application (Xcode 4.5 iOS 6), it must be compatible for the devices that have installed software version, starting at 4.5 and default iPhone 5.

I know that the new iOS 6 changes came with the auto-rotate mode.

When you turn on your device "iPhone Simulator 6.0" application behaves normally but when I run the "iPhone Simulator 5.0" problems in the way of rotation.

I put in the code, along with new ways to rotate from iOS 6 and the old method (deprecated) to iOS 5.

So look for the rotate methods:

```
#pragma mark - Rotate Methods iOS 5




- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

{

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation))

{

    //Code Here

}


if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation))

{

    //Code Here

}

return YES;
```

}

```
#pragma mark - Rotate Methods iOS 6
```

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
  duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

  {

if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation))

```
    {

        //Code here

    }
```

if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation))

```
    {

         //Code here

    }
```

}